# Why are there time bubbles in my GPU timeline even when triple buffering?

Tags: directx, directx-12

I'm having trouble understanding why there are time bubbles on my GPU timeline when inspecting my app using PIX timing captures. Here is a picture of one of the time bubbles I'm talking about, highlighted in orange:
[image]

The timeline actually doesn't look at all how I expected. Since I am triple buffering, I would expect the GPU to be constantly working, without any time gaps between frames because the CPU is easily able to feed commands to the GPU before the GPU is done processing them. Instead, it doesn't seem like the CPU is 3 frames ahead. It seems like the CPU is constantly waiting for the GPU to be finished before it starts working on a new frame. So it makes me wonder if my triple buffering code is possibly broken? Here is my code for moving to the next frame:

```
void gpu_interface::next_frame()
{
    UINT64 current_frame_fence_value = get_frame_resource()->fence_value;
    UINT64 next_frame_fence_value = current_frame_fence_value + 1;

    check_hr(swapchain->Present(0, 0));
    check_hr(graphics_cmd_queue->Signal(fence.Get(), current_frame_fence_value));

    {
        // CPU and GPU frame-to-frame event.
        PIXEndEvent(graphics_cmd_queue.Get());
        PIXBeginEvent(graphics_cmd_queue.Get(), 0, "fence value: %d", next_frame_fence_value);
    }

    // Check if the next frame is ready to be rendered.
    // The GPU must have reached at least up to the fence value of the frame we're about to render.
    if (fence->GetCompletedValue() < current_frame_fence_value)
    {
        PIXBeginEvent(0, "CPU Waiting for GPU to reach fence value: %d", current_frame_fence_value);
        // Wait for the next frame resource to be ready
        fence->SetEventOnCompletion(current_frame_fence_value, fence_event);
        WaitForSingleObject(fence_event, INFINITE);
        PIXEndEvent();
    }
    // Next frame is ready to be rendered

    // Update the frame_index. GetCurrentBackBufferIndex() gets incremented after swapchain->Present() calls.
    frame_index = swapchain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex();
    frames[frame_index].fence_value = next_frame_fence_value;
}
```

Here's the whole timing capture: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiGFMy6hVmtNgaky52n7QDrQ6o7V1A?e=MFc4xW

EDIT: Fixed answer

```
void gpu_interface::next_frame()
{
    check_hr(swapchain->Present(0, 0));

    UINT64 current_frame_fence_value = get_frame_resource()->fence_value;
    UINT64 next_frame_fence_value = current_frame_fence_value + 1;

    check_hr(graphics_cmd_queue->Signal(fence.Get(), current_frame_fence_value));

    //// Update the frame_index. GetCurrentBackBufferIndex() gets incremented after swapchain->Present() calls.
    frame_index = swapchain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex();

    // The GPU must have reached at least up to the fence value of the frame we're about to render.
    size_t minimum_fence = get_frame_resource()->fence_value;
    size_t completed = fence->GetCompletedValue();
    if (completed < minimum_fence)
    {
        PIXBeginEvent(0, "CPU Waiting for GPU to reach fence value: %d", minimum_fence);
        // Wait for the next frame resource to be ready
        fence->SetEventOnCompletion(minimum_fence, fence_event);
        WaitForSingleObject(fence_event, INFINITE);
        PIXEndEvent();
    }

    frames[frame_index].fence_value = next_frame_fence_value;

    {
        // CPU and GPU frame-to-frame event.
        PIXEndEvent(graphics_cmd_queue.Get());
        PIXBeginEvent(graphics_cmd_queue.Get(), 0, "fence value: %d", next_frame_fence_value);
    }
}
```

Timing capture of the correct code: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiGFMy6hVmtNgakzGizTiA_s-FwPqA?e=qIHHTw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You signal the queue with `current_frame_fence_value` and right after you check

```
if (fence->GetCompletedValue() < current_frame_fence_value)
```

if the fence completed that value. You need to check the fence value for the next frame to see if you can continue and that is `fence_values[frame_index]` where `frame_index` is updated. It would go something like this:

```
void gpu_interface::next_frame()
{
    check_hr(swapchain->Present(0, 0));

    UINT64 current_frame_fence_value = get_frame_resource()->fence_value;

    check_hr(graphics_cmd_queue->Signal(fence.Get(), current_frame_fence_value));

    UINT64 next_frame_fence_value = current_frame_fence_value + 1;

    frame_index = swapchain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex();

    // The GPU must have reached at least up to the fence value of the frame we're about to render.
    //current_frame_fence_value is not the fence value of the frame you are about the render, it is fence_values[frame_index]
    //note that frame_index is updated before this call
    if (fence->GetCompletedValue() < fence_values[frame_index])
    {
        // Wait for the next frame resource to be ready
        fence->SetEventOnCompletion(fence_values[frame_index], fence_event);
        WaitForSingleObject(fence_event, INFINITE);
    }

    frames[frame_index].fence_value = next_frame_fence_value;
}
```

Try writing down fence values for the first few frames to see how that works.

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me, I posted the exact code that worked for me (`fence_values[frame_index]` isn't part of my code). I also attached a link to a timing capture that shows the result of the fixed code. Do you think you could take a quick peek and let me know if it looks right to you as well? I would really appreciate it just to confirm that it all works as expected.

Comment: @mbl it seems ok now. You can notice yourself that you rarely see message "CPU waiting for GPU to reach fence value", and in cases when you do it's because CPU is much more ahead of GPU.